# Spark: Weird partitioning on join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL query that works somewhat like this (actual fields have been omitted):

```
SELECT
  a1.fieldA,
  a1.fieldB,
  a1.fieldC,
  a1.fieldD,
  a1.joinType
FROM sample_a a1
WHERE a1.joinType != "test"
UNION
SELECT
  a2.fieldA,
  a2.fieldB,
  a2.fieldC,
  b.fieldD,
  a2.joinType
FROM sample_a a2
INNER JOIN sample_b b ON b.joinField = a2.joinField
WHERE a2.joinType = "test"
```

This is working perfectly fine but Spark will read sample_a twice. (From cache or disk)
I'm trying to get rid of the union and came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT
  a.fieldA,
  a.fieldB,
  a.fieldC,
  a.joinType,
  CASE WHEN a.joinType = "test" THEN b.fieldD ELSE a.fieldD END as fieldD
FROM sample_a a
LEFT JOIN sample_b b ON a.joinType = "test" AND a.joinField = b.joinField
WHERE a.joinType != "test" OR (a.joinType = "test" AND b.joinField IS NOT NULL)
```

This should basically do the same thing but Spark is being very weird about it. While the first one keeps the partitions the same as sample_a (~1200) the second one will go down to 200 partitions, which is what sample_b has. It will also put a lot of data into a single partition. (Around 90% of data is in one of the 200 partitions)

The input data is stored in parquet files and not partitioned in any way. While sample_a has a much bigger file size, the `joinField` values for our `joinType = "test"` part are a subset of the `joinField` values in sample_b.

Edit: The physical plans look like this.

First Query:

```
Union
:- *(1) Project [fieldA#0, fieldD#1 joinType#2, joinField#3]
:  +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(joinType#2) && NOT (joinType#2 = test))
:     +- *(1) FileScan parquet [fieldA#0, fieldD#1 joinType#2, joinField#3] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[...], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(joinType), Not(EqualTo(joinType,test))], ReadSchema: struct<fieldA:string,fieldD:string,joinType:string,joinField:string>
+- *(6) Project [fieldA#0, fieldD#4 joinType#2, joinField#3]
   +- *(6) SortMergeJoin [joinField#3], [joinField#5], Inner
      :- *(3) Sort [joinField#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(joinField#3, 200)
      :     +- *(2) Project [fieldA#0, fieldD#1 joinType#2, joinField#3]
      :        +- *(2) Filter ((isnotnull(joinType#2) && (joinType#2 = test)) && isnotnull(joinField#3))
      :           +- *(2) FileScan parquet [fieldA#0, fieldD#1 joinType#2, joinField#3] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[...], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(joinType), EqualTo(joinType,test), IsNotNull(joinField)], ReadSchema: struct<fieldA:string,fieldD:string,joinType:string,joinField:string>
      +- *(5) Sort [joinField#5 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(joinField#5, 200)
            +- *(4) FileScan parquet [fieldD#4, joinField#5] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[...], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fieldD:string,joinField:string>
```

Second Query:

```
*(5) Project [fieldA#0, CASE WHEN (joinType#2 = test) THEN fieldD#4 ELSE fieldD#1 END AS fieldD#6, joinType#2, joinField#3]
+- *(5) Filter (NOT (joinType#2 = test) || ((joinType#2 = test) && isnotnull(joinField#5)))
   +- SortMergeJoin [joinField#3], [joinField#5], LeftOuter, (joinType#2 = test)
      :- *(2) Sort [joinField#3 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(joinField#3, 200)
      :     +- *(1) FileScan parquet [fieldA#0, fieldD#1 joinType#2, joinField#3] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[...], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fieldA:string,fieldD:string,joinType:string,joinField:string>
      +- *(4) Sort [joinField#5 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(joinField#5, 200)
            +- *(3) FileScan parquet [fieldD#4, joinField#5] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[...], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<fieldD:string,joinField:string>
```

Comment: Can you post the `.explain()` for your second query?

Comment: And 1st query pls

Comment: Isn't this just because spark will do a shuffle stage and repartitions it to the 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' which is set to 200 by default?

Comment: @thebluephantom I added the physical plans for these queries

Comment: @ferdyh That might be the reason why it's partitioning it to 200 partitions but the real problem is the very uneven distribution since 90% of all rows are in one of the 200 partitions.